# Conditionally exclude one sibling object property depends on other sibling object's property in JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a JSON having two siblings JSON objects and I would like to have a schema where the below condition can satisfy:

I need a schema, where I need the attribute 'referee' in the 2nd object when there is no HARD_RULES OR SOFT_RULES enum in 1st object.

However, in the presence of HARD_RULES OR SOFT_RULES enum from object1, the attribute 'referee' in the 2nd object should be ignored or discarded.

Please note that:

1. I need both object1 and 2 in when SOFT/HARD rule are there.
2. I need object2 when object1 is entirely unavailable as there are no SOFT/HARD rules.
3. The 'referee' is mandatory in object2 when there is no HARD_RULES OR SOFT_RULES enum in 1st object.

```
{
    "items": [{//Object 1
        "required": ["host"],
        "properties": {
            "type": {
                "enum": ["HARD_RULES", "SOFT_RULES"],
                "type": "string"
            },
            "host": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }, {//Object 2
        "required": ["refree"],
        "properties": {
            "type": {
                "enum": ["INDOOR"],
                "type": "string"
            },
            "refree": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Some examples:

```
//valid 1
{
  "items":[
  {
    "type":"HARD_RULES",
    "host": "some-host",
    "age":10
  },
  {
    "type":"INDOOR",
    "time":"some-time"
    //no referee here
  }
  ]
}

//valid 2
{
  "items":[
  {
    "type":"SOFT_RULES",
    "host": "some-host",
    "age":10
  },
  {
    "type":"INDOOR",
    "time":"some-time"
    //no referee here
  }
  ]
}

//valid 3
{
  "items":[{
    "type":"INDOOR",
    "time":"some-time",
    "refree":"Tom"  // referee here
  }]
}

//invalid
{
  "items":[
  {
    "type":"SOFT_RULES",
    "host": "some-host",
    "age":10
  },
  {
    "type":"INDOOR",
    "time":"some-time",
    "refree":"Tom"  // referee cannot be here as we have SOFT_RULES above
  }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, where did you gain your understanding of JSON Schema so far? (We are trying to improve our educational resources)

Comment: I see you've updated your question so you have a valid JSON Schema. Can you also provide an example valid and invalid JSON instance please? =]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using draf-7 here.

You need to wrap your two subschemas in a `oneOf` array.

This means that ONE OF the schemas must be valid, not more than one, not none.

You'll also need to add `additionalProperties: false` to each subschema.

You were pretty close to getting this!

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. But I want both objects, but object2's property must be excluded depends on 1st object's enum property

Comment: OK. That's a little confusing as you haven't shown your JSON, and what you have provided is not valid JSON either. Please can you update your question to include example JSON and your Schema so far? =]